# R -- coerces other elements to character when unlisted

Tags: r, list

I am not able to understand this behavior of R.

```
a <- list("a" = 1, "b" = 2, "c" = NA, "d" = Inf)
vec <- unlist(a, use.names=FALSE)
print(vec)
[1]   1   2  NA Inf
```

When there is a character value in the list it coerces all the unlisted values to character. Why is this done? And, why is NA *not* coerced to character?

```
a = list("a" = 1, "b" = 2, "c" = NA, "d" = Inf, "e" = "pass")
vec = unlist(a, use.names=FALSE)
print(vec)
[1] "1"    "2"    NA     "Inf"  "pass"
```

Comment: `unlist` converts it in to a vector. A vector can only have one `class` e.g. numeric, character, integer. Character takes precedent as its possible to turn 2 in to "2" but not possible to turn "pass" in to a number. In fact, if you do `?unlist` there is the order of hierarchy in Details e.g. `Vectors will be coerced to the highest type of the components in the hierarchy NULL < raw < logical < integer < double < complex < character < list < expression: pairlists are treated as lists.`

Comment: As you say a vector can have only one class -- but class(NA) is "logical" while other elements of the vector are characters.

Comment: `class(vec)` is character. You can have `NA` values within vectors of each class. Taking `class(NA)` on its own isn't that useful, as each value in the vector has to have the same class as a collective

Comment: Did not know if NA is allowed within vectors of each class. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a brief summary of properties of lists and vectors. More details can be found in [this book](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html).

Broadly speaking, there are two different one-dimensional data structures in R.

1. Atomic vectors: all elements of an atomic vector must be the same type
2. Lists:  the elements of a list can have different types

All elements of an atomic vector must be the same type, so when you attempt to combine different types they will be coerced to the most flexible type. Types from least to most flexible are: logical, integer, double, and character.

For example, combining a character and an integer yields a character:

```
str(c("a", 1))
```

As you see: coercion often happens automatically.